# How to find the value of the array object after push in Angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I have an array defined in angular2 .ts file as -

```
this.dropdownValue=[];
```

And then i push values into them from different functions like -

```
 this.dropdownValue.push({ item_text: this.organizationInfo.records[i]._fields[0].end.properties.name });

  this.dropdownValue.push({ item_text: this.departmentInfo.records[i]._fields[0].end.properties.name });
```

The Console statements -

```
console.log("inside Proceed, this.dropdownValue =", typeof(this.dropdownValue));

console.log("inside Proceed, this.dropdownValue =", this.dropdownValue);

console.log("inside Proceed, this.dropdownValue =", this.dropdownValue[0]);

console.log("inside Proceed, this.dropdownValue =", this.dropdownValue.length);
```

There Outputs of a few values are -

```
 typeOf(this.dropdownValue ) = object

 this.dropdownValue = 
[
0:{item_text: "IT"}
1:{item_text: "post"}
2:{item_text: "intimationDate"}
3:{item_text: "lossDescription"}
]

  this.dropdownValue[0] = undefined

  this.dropdownValue.length = 0
```

I want to access the values of  -

```
  item_text
```

.i.e store it in another variable/array.

And i am unable to do so.Neither am i able to access these values, no find its length nor find the value at a particular length
PLease help

Comment: What is `this.dropdownValue[0] = undefined` and `this.dropdownValue.length = 0`? its your output or are you assigning these values?

Comment: `this.dropdownValue.find((elem) => elem.item_text === "IT")` should work in case the texts are unique, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Hi Ashish,  Thanks. this.dropdownValue[0] = undefined and this.dropdownValue.length = 0 are the outputs. And i don't wanna hardcode it. Like - you did --> === "IT". I want to place the entire item_text values into a variable

Comment: If those are the outputs, then it seems you are accessing the array before it is populated? maybe outside some subscription, while the array under subscription. Is it getting populated throughsome async request?

Comment: And you want to store in a variable? How many variables will you make then? Another variable which is an array containg the `item_text` would be better in that case then

Comment: Yeah actually i populates the value of this.dropdownValue through http requests in the same function. Probably i shall change its location. But either way i wanna access item_text: "something"  ..which i am unable to do so

Comment: You see, until you have values populated there is no point in accessing them, access them in your subscription itself. Or make a method where you write your logic for accessing and using them, call this method from under your subscription.

Comment: Ok thanks. I shall follow it and see. Is that the reason, i am getting length = 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let otherVariable = this.dropdownValue.find(x => x.item_text === 'IT');
```

I edit my answer because I undestood right now what you are looking for.

```
let otherArray = []; 
for (let obj of this.dropdownValue) {
 otherArray.push(obj.item_text);
}
```

I know that is not the best way to do, but when i have to do something similar, i always do that

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Hey Matias, thanks for the reply. I corrected my question. I want to accumulate all item_text from the array.